# Is there a requiredFalse method in Java 8 for argument checking?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I want to check arguments in a method. I've found the *Objects.requireNonNull* method which makes the code easily readable.
Is it some similar build in solution for boolean checking?
I want a similar syntax to this:

```
SomeJavaObject.requiredFalse(myArgument < 0, "myArgument can not be negative!");
```

(I can write my own method, but I prefer using the built in java functions.)

Comment: I do not know such check - for such I wrote my own `Objects` class, obviously with a different name like `Check`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have the Apache Commons libraries in our project anyways, I tend to use the checks in the `Validate` class from time to time: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html

There is similar stuff in Guava's `Preconditions` class, but I prefer `Validate`.

We decided to avoid the `assert` keyword because code running on a customer's machine would then have different execution paths than during local development, making it harder to debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [assert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) keyword.

```
int a = -1;
assert a >= 0 : "Parameter passed to foo() can't be negative";
```

The code above will throw an `AssertionError` if you launch it with `-enableassertions` or `-ea` for short.

> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Parameter passed to foo() can't be negative

Keep in mind that `assert` by no means should be used to validate arguments passed to public methods, or even worse - user input, because they are disabled by default. Yes, they can be disabled, and this is not a pitfall of `assert`, but a conscious and deliberate design choice. Why you can't use that in some cases is clearly written in the official Oracle guideline:

> Argument checking is typically part of the published specifications (or contract) of a method, and these specifications must be obeyed whether assertions are enabled or disabled. Another problem with using assertions for argument checking is that erroneous arguments should result in an appropriate runtime exception (such as IllegalArgumentException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, or NullPointerException). An assertion failure will not throw an appropriate exception.

That does not mean that using `assert` should be avoided and is considered a bad practice. Assertion is **not** equal to error handling. The key is to use the right tool for the right job. Assertions are useful at catching programmers' mistakes - to make sure that something regarded as impossible indeed does never happen - for example:

1. Checking if a variable in a private method does not have an unexpected value, as stated in the guideline:

   > You can, however, use an assertion to test a nonpublic method's precondition that you believe will be true no matter what a client does with the class.
2. Marking a block of code that should never be reached with `assert false`.

Comment: `assert` for method argument checking is not safe: they can be disabled

Comment: @dfogni You can programmatically force assertions to be enabled

Comment: @dfogni and that's a deliberate decision. Assertions can, and are used for argument checking, but they're not suited for error handling. When I saw "myArgument can not be negative!", my first thought was - that looks like an invariant.

Comment: Josh Bloch recommends reserving `assert` for nonpublic methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in the standard API and there are some reasons, not to add it. While `Objects.requireNonNull` will throw a dedicated exception, `NullPointerException`, there is no such obvious exception type for a method that tests an arbitrary predicate. If the predicate is testing a parameter value, an `IllegalArgumentException` might be appropriate, otherwise, an `IllegalStateException` or something completely different would fit better. You might consider an API with a `Supplier` for the exception, but this leads to the second issue.

If you want to support a supplier for the exception, you need a capturing lambda expression if you want to provide a message that includes the illegal value. And the overhead might be simply too much for parameter checking. The same would apply to a `String` parameter as it has to be constructed before invoking the utility method. This differs from the `requireNonNull` test where the illegal value invariably is `null`.

While HotSpot might be good at eliminating such overhead, the API is the standard for *all* JREs, including those not having such an optimization potential.

Besides that, it would make more sense to have a naming like

```
require(myArgument >= 0, "myArgument can not be negative!");
```

instead of forcing the reader to decipher a negation.

Since it’s more common to have multiple methods with similar constraints in one class, the established pattern is to have a more tailored method, e.g.

```
checkPositive("myArgument", myArgument);

…

private void checkPositive(String name, int arg) {
    if(arg<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(name+" is negative");
}
```

See for example [`rangeCheck` in `ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#644) or [`checkIndex` in NIO `Buffer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/Buffer.java#532)

Answer (score -1):

Afaik there's no such method. What I usually do is this:

```
if(myArgument < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("myArgument must be greater or equal to 0");
```

(and repeat for each parameter check)

You can also use assertions, altho those aren't always welcome in production code.